# Concatenate a string with a new line in bash

Tags: bash, shell, newline

```
#!/bin/bash

message=""

for f in /mnt/backup/*; do
    if [ -d "$f" ]; then
        message+="${f} is a folder"$'\n'
    fi
done

if [ -z "$message" ]; then
    echo "No folders found"
fi

echo "$message"
```

I have this code and i wanna append text and a new line to the message. This is almost working fine. However it outputs something like this:

```
/mnt/backup/a is a folder
/mnt/backup/b is a folder
/mnt/backup/c is a folder
/mnt/backup/d is a folder /mnt/backup/e is a folder
```

Does anybody know why the last folder is written next to the previous one?

Edit: When i echo this message it prints out fine. But when i try to send that message via mail it outputs the message like described above.

Comment: Use `printf -v message '%s%s is a folder\n' "$message" "$f"`

Comment: Your script works perfectly well here. What do you mean by _does not work_? What is your shell (are you 100% sure it is bash)? Do you really have sub-directories in `/mnt/backup`?

Comment: what is the output from running `/bin/bash --version`? after the `for` loop what does `typeset -p message` generate? please update the question with these results

Comment: Edited the post, I am using bash and there are folders in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash

message=""

for f in aaa bbb ccc; do
    message+="${f} is a folder"$'\n'
done

echo "$message"
```

Maybe you tried `echo $message`, etc. This would cause the shell to interpret lines as separated by whitespace, since a newline character is also a whitespace character, and it would be split there. To prevent this, double quotes are necessary.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I used $message. But there is a sligth issue with this. All folders are listed below each other exept the last one, which is next to the one before.

Comment: If you find that the value of `message` is as expected, and you are quoting it as `"$message"` and passing it to mail, then I think the next thing to debug is mail. Not the shell script.